# Why i can not push a view controller in my navigationController?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my navigation based application, first view is sign in or signup view. After that i am using a view which is using tab view controller. That view has three tab items. Now i want to create a new view and push in navigationController. But its not working. But adding new view as subView in tabBarController View works. I want navigation for subViews for each tabBarItem? How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/06/25/uitabbarcontroller-with-uinavigationcontroller-using-interface-builder/)

In your case just create three items and make them all UINavigationControllers like the first tab item in the above example.

Comment: In this example rootViewController is TabBarController view. In my case i have Sign in and sign up view before TabBarController view. I made a navigation based application. Should i start with simple window based application?

Comment: Yes. start window based (my advice, personally I find it easier programatically). use a modal view for sign in/sign up over the initial UITabBarController. Then on each tab you have UINavigationController just like the above example has for the first tab. Simples.

Comment: one last thing, when i make a view and add TabBarController, i don't get Tab Bar Navigation App Delegate. But if you start with TabBar application, it comes automatically. Will i have to do it manually in my case. Sorry i am quite new with this stuff.

Comment: Best option would be to go window based and programatically create all your viewControllers.

Comment: http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-tabbar-uitabbarcontroller-tutorial/ - example for tab bar controller on a window based app. Uses IB too if you find it difficult to add it programatically.